# Open Authentication - provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, oauth

I hope someone can at least point me in the right direction here.

I have a need for **Open Authentication** in my business.

However it is **not** to use other services like **facebook or google** etc.

We have a **membership database - a standard asp.net membership database** (slightly modified with an additional table for profile information).

We also have **multiple applications that our customers can use** but require a log in, so we would like to use the membership database as an authentication source for these applications using open auth.

But i'm not sure where to start with it... everything i look at seems to point to using facebook or google etc as the source of authentication.

Where do I start with being the provider for open auth?

Any recommendations? Any advice for a newbie to open auth?

Our website is webforms, not mvc and runs on .net 4.0.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you might want to have a look at http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services where this page explains how open auth works and how you may use it with C# (and thus ASP.NET as well). Usually you will have an external resource providing the oauth data to interface with.

Comment: again... this seems to focus on the facebook, google. microsoft etc being the source of authentication. the source of authetication i need to be our own .net memberhsip database :(

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general software *design* rather than a specific programming problem. It would likely get a better response on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Try to look at [Thinktecture IdentityServer v2](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2). It is an IAM that handles authentication. It is customizable. With little coding you can wire your membership database with it. See [this page](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/05/17/customizing-identityserver/) and [IdentityServer wiki](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You should start looking at the code from [DotNetopenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/%20DotNetOpenAuth), particularly the [Samples](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth.Samples). This is should give you enough to get started with OAuth and/or Open ID.

Particurlarly, look at [this](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples/OAuth2ProtectedWebApi) sample, as this uses OAuth2 to protect a web api, which can be used a starting point to something that can be used by clients in a very similar way to facebook or google logins.